# Realm Swift: Results getting notifications even though there is no data change (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a model called CardDetails

```
public class CardDetails: Object {

  @objc public dynamic var id : Int = 0
  @objc public dynamic var number : String?
  @objc public dynamic var name : String?
  @objc public dynamic var status : String?

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "id"
    }

    override public static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
      return ["status"]
    }
}
```

The object is written on a background thread when we fetch data from the API

```
let realm = try Realm()
try realm.write {
  for card in cardsList {
    realm.add(card,update: true)
  }
}
```

I have used a NotificationToken as follows in the ViewController

```
var cardResults: Results<CardDetails>!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()       
  cardResults = realm.objects(CardDetails.self).filter("status = %@", "ACTIVE")
  tokenCards = cardResults.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
    switch(changes) {
    case .initial, .update:
      self?.setUpCardUI()
    case .error(let error):
            // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
      fatalError("\(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting a call to setUpCardUI on each call to the card fetching endpoint though data isn't changed (there is only one active card!). This is leading to unexpected UI behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Realm will always send modification changes when updating an object regardless if the data changed, which is a bummer, however, this doesn't mean we can't fix the problem and even implement some nice improvements.

Instead of reloading the whole table view when changes are observed we want to insert, delete or reload cells manually. I wrote an extension to do this on a tableview.

```
import UIKit

// RealmDiff is just a lightweight struct to make passing the changes around cleaner
// public struct RealmDiff {
//    let deletions: [Int]
//    let insertions: [Int]
//    let modifications: [Int]
//}

extension UITableView {
    func reload(section: Int = 0, with diff: RealmDiff?, update: ((UITableViewCell, IndexPath) -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard let diff = diff else {
            reloadData()
            return
        }

        beginUpdates()
        insertRows(at: diff.insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }), with: .automatic)
        deleteRows(at: diff.deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }), with: .automatic)

        guard update != nil else {
            reloadRows(at: diff.modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }), with: .fade)
            endUpdates()
            return
        }

        endUpdates()

        let indexPaths = diff.modifications
            .map ({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
            .filter { indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains($0) ?? false }

        indexPaths.forEach {
            if let cell = cellForRow(at: $0) {
                update?(cell, $0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By default, this will still exchange all the cells, which will likely still cause the table view to jump depending on your implementation of the layout. But we can also pass a closure to manually change the data on the cell. Here is an example of the extension in use:

```
tableView.reload(with: diff) { [weak self] cell, indexPath in
    if let cell = cell as? MyCellClass {
        MyCellClass.configure(cell: cell, with: myDataSourceDataArray[indexPath.row], delegate: self)
    }
}
```

This way you are using the same cell and no reload is needed. I find this method to work really well and is very reusable.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting update to false and updating the UI once the writing has finished.

```
let realm = try Realm()
try realm.write {
  for card in cardsList {
    realm.add(card,update: false)
 }
 //Perhaps try updating the UI when it finished writing to realm
}
```

Comment: This won't work. If there are any changes in the data, .update case is triggered and .initial case is basically the didSet that you have suggested in my view.

Comment: try putting a couple of print statements into the case .initial, .update and when it is getting triggered then you might be able to narrow down the issue.

Comment: done all that, that only concluded that they are being called multiple times even if there is no data change. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link where I could try your code to see if I can help debugging it?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3489 Other people apparently have also faced this issue and actually hoping a realm contributer can help out on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of a big disadvantages of the realm. There is how it look in my case: 
[image]

What is happening:

1) I fetch existing in realm data an show it.
2) Load new data from the server.
3) It comes the SAME data, but the realm still sends modification changes in it's notification.
Because of that the tableView jumps up, when the data return from the server and notification block fired.

There are realm issues about that: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5451, https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2787, https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3489